# Index out of bounds in embedded python script

Tags: python, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I keep getting an index out of bounds error on the line:

```
output_items [0][y] = 1
```

or

```
output_items[0][y]=0
```

I have tried everything I can think of to fix it but I don't know. This is a custom python block in GNU Radio and GNU does something weird with output items and how they output. If you have GNURadio installed it might help you with troubleshooting. Any help or tips would be great I have been fighting this error for a few hours now and have exhausted what I can think of to fix. Code below:

```
"""

Ascii to Morse code vector source

"""



import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr


Morse = {
  # codes from https://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-M.1677-1-200910-I/en
    "A": "1,0,1,1,1",
    "B": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1",
    "C": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",
    "D": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1",
    "E": "1",
    "F": "1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",
    "G": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",
    "H": "1,0,1,0,1,0,1",
    "I": "1,0,1",
    "J": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "K": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",
    "L": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1",
    "M": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "N": "1,1,1,0,1",
    "O": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "P": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",
    "Q": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",
    "R": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1",
    "S": "1,0,1,0,1",
    "T": "1,1,1",
    "U": "1,0,1,0,1,1,1",
    "V": "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",
    "W": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "X": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",
    "Y": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "Z": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1",
    " ": "0",            # space
    "1": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "2": "1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "3": "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    "4": "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",
    "5": "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1",
    "6": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1",
    "7": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1",
    "8": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1",
    "9": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",
    "0": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",
    ".": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",          # period
    ",": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",      # comma
    ":": "1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1",          # colon
    "?": "1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1",              # question
    "'": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",      # apostrophe
    "-": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",              # dash or minus
    "/": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",                  # slash
    "(": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",              # left parenthesis
    ")": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",      # right parenthesis
    "\"": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",             # quote
    "=": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",                  # equals
    "+": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",                  # plus
    "@": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",          # at sign (@)
  # these punctuation marks are not included in the ITU recommendation,
  # but are found in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code
    "!": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1",      # exclamation point
    "&": "1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1",                      # ampersand (also prosign for 'WAIT')
    ";": "1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1",          # semicolon
    "_": "1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1",          # underscore
    "$": "1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1"           # dollar sign
      }

class mc_sync_block(gr.sync_block):
    """
    Reads an input ascii message from the "Message" textbox and converts the message to morse code and repeats 
    """
    def __init__(self, Message = ''):
        gr.sync_block.__init__(self,
            name = "Ascii Message to Morse Code Vector Source",
            in_sig = None, #disables the input port on GRC block
            out_sig = [np.byte]
        )
        
    self.Message = Message # creates callback of Message
    
    
    def work(self, input_items, output_items):
        global Morse
        bit_stream = ""
        if (len (self.Message) > 0):
            for in0 in self.Message:
                # get next char
                inChar = str (in0)
                # convert to upper case
                ch = inChar.upper()
                # test for character in table
                if (not(ch in Morse)):
                    ch = "?"        # replace bad character with a '?'
                # build vector
                dots = str (Morse.get(ch))
                bit_stream += (dots + ",0,0,0,")    # letter space

            bit_stream += "0,0,0,0"    # finish with word space
            

            # get length of string
            len1 = len(bit_stream)
            # num of elements = (length+1) / 2
            num_elem = int((len1+1) / 2) 
            # convert and store elements in output array
            for x in range (0,len1):
                y = int(x / 2)
                if (bit_stream[x] == '1'):
                    output_items[0][y] = 1
                elif (bit_stream[x] == '0'):
                    output_items[0][y] = 0
                else:
                    continue                    # skip commas
            
        else:
            num_elem = 0

        return (num_elem)
```

Comment: What is the value of `output_items[0]` when you do this? You can't create new elements of a list by assigning to an index.

Comment: `self.Message = Message` needs to be inside a method. There's no `self` at the top-level of the class definition.

Comment: Where's the full traceback? This cannot be the entire code, `mc_sync_block.work` is not called.

Comment: Why are you using strings like `"1,0,1"` instead of lists like `[1, 0, 1]`? You have to do lots of extra work to skip over the commas.

Comment: I handle the string the way I do because the script reads a user input message from the python block in GNU radio

Comment: type(output_items[0]) ? please

Comment: @AajKaal the type is int

Comment: @Countour-Integral This is an embedded python script in GNU Radio. The code mc_sync_block.work is called somewhere in their backend of the GUI. They provide you a structure to write your own block and you fill it in

Comment: @Barmar self.Message is generated by their predefined structure. It has to stay where it is. My code functions fine and I don't see anything going wrong but it throws this error